# Are there alternatives to CGPDFContext?

Tags: macos, pdf, core-graphics

I am aiming to combine multiple PDF files each with identical dimensions into one file.

I've seen how it is done with CGPDFContext. I am just curious if there are (better?) alternatives to this method on the Mac.

Let's say I have the option to use PDFs, TIFF, PNG or JPEG files as input. Would using a different input file type mean anything significant for the process, or it would be easier to go with PDF input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use PDFDocument API and it is programmatically easier to use. It may need PDF files as input though.